# How can I convert an SQL Recursive Query Result to JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json, data-structures

I have the code below from an Oracle article here (it is using 10g; I am using 11gR2),

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/bollweg-easytrees-083408.html

It works great.  I then adapted it to my other schemas.  Still works.

But, I want to get it as JSON, nested just like it is with the tags.  I have tried all kinds of things, but can't get it.  I want it to get like,

```
name:'employee'
children:[
   {
       name:'employee',
       children:[
          {
etc.
```

I have tried:

```
    if ($row['LEVEL']==$top_level)
                {
                    $name['children'][$node]['children'][$node]['children'][]=array('name'=>$_name . ' childLevel->' . $row['LEVEL'] .' rowNum->' . $row['ROWNUM']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $name['children'][$node]['children'][]=array('name'=>$_name . ' childLevel->' . $row['LEVEL'] .' rowNum->' . $row['ROWNUM']);
                }
later on json_encode($name);
...
```

but it ends up one layer deeper each time (as expected).  I have tried recursion where I send the previous ID into a new query and avoid this entire query below, but I can't get the array nesting correct.  I understand how to echo out an HTML tree of lists (I understand what's going on in the code, not just copy and paste), but not the nested JSON.

Here is what the Oracle article has:

```
<?php 
    /*  file:           functional.php
        phpversion: 5.1.1
    version:        1.0
    author:     nick bollweg <nickD0TbollwegATgmailD0Tcom>
    purpose:        demonstrate basic CONNECT BY functionality with Oracle 10g
                using a functional approach. */
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
     <title>CONNECT BY and array_map &raquo; a functional approach</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
<?php

// open a connection. change these values to fit your situation
$conn = oci_connect( "scott", "tiger", "//localhost/testdb" );
$results = array();
if( !$conn ) {
  exit;
}

//build a statement
$stmt = oci_parse( $conn, 
"   SELECT ENAME, JOB, EMPNO, MGR, LEVEL
         FROM EMP 
       CONNECT BY MGR = PRIOR EMPNO 
       START WITH MGR IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ENAME");

// execute statement
oci_execute( $stmt );

// fetch the results
$nrows = oci_fetch_all ( $stmt, $results, 0, 0, 
              OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW );

// we need this value accessible inside the formatting function
global $last;

// set a value not possible in a LEVEL column to allow the 
// first row to know it's "firstness"
$last = null;

// add a dummy "row" to cap off formatting
$results[] = array();
$formatted = array_map( "treeFunc", $results );

//output the results
echo implode( "\n",$formatted );

// clean up statement and connection
oci_free_statement( $stmt );
oci_close( $conn );

function treeFunc( $current ) {
    // the previous row's level, or null on the first row
    global $last;

    // structural elements
    $openItem =     '<li>';
    $closeItem =    '</li>';
    $openChildren = '<ul>';
    $closeChildren =    '</ul>';
    $structure = "";

    if( !isset( $current['LEVEL'] ) ) {
        // add closing structure(s) equal to the very last
        // row's level; this will only fire for the "dummy"
        return str_repeat( $closeItem.$closeChildren, 
            $last );
    }

    // add the item itself
    $item = "{$current['ENAME']} <i>{$current['JOB']}</i>";

    if( is_null( $last ) ) {
        // add the opening structure in the case of
        // the first row
        $structure .= $openChildren; 
    } elseif( $last < $current['LEVEL'] ){
        // add the structure to start new branches
        $structure .= $openChildren;
    } elseif( $last > $current['LEVEL'] ) {
        // add the structure to close branches equal to the 
        // difference between the previous and current levels
        $structure .= $closeItem.
               str_repeat( $closeChildren.$closeItem, 
                $last - $current['LEVEL'] );
    } else {
        $structure .= $closeItem;
    }

    // add the item structure
    $structure .= $openItem;

    // update $last so the next row knows whether this row is
    // really its parent
    $last = $current['LEVEL'];

    return $structure.$item;
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```